# app built gives success but doesn't launch on my iphone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Often when i try to run my app on my device it is a success but doesn't launch on my iphone device. Message is Finish running application

Comment: Have you set the target at topLeft corner of XCode?

Comment: Have you mapped your iPhone at `iOS Provisioning Portal`?

Comment: it runs well on iphone device usually, but sometimes it doesn't launch my app

Comment: Well, try `Cmd+.` to quit the app, clean your build & rebuild, run.

Comment: what iOS SDK, XCode and device you are using? for me this happened when my architecture was set to armv7 and problem resolved when I set it to armv6 + armv7

Comment: It happens to me all the time.. Standard procedure (continue to next step if it previous does not solve the issue), reconnect device, close and open xCode, reset device (hold down both buttons till it turns off), restart mac.

Comment: @chatur how can i set my architecture

Comment: for Xcode4.2 double click on project icon at right upper corner. then Project-> Build Settings-> Architecture

Comment: @MaticOblak restart mac? Oh, It seems you met a issue that I had before. You need to make sure quit the app successfully by `Cmd+.`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran through the same problem. A lot of applications were running in the background mode in the device. I restarted the device and killed all the background apps. This time when I ran my app from Xcode it worked on the device.